# SQLite update trigger to resize number of rows in another table

Tags: sqlite, triggers, resize, rows

I'm trying to create an update trigger for one table that resizes another table by adding or deleting rows so that the final number of rows in the second table matches a value from the first table. Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Options" (
    "Num" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Post" INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE "Weights" (
    "Weight" REAL NOT NULL);
```

The Options table is meant to only have one row, and when the user changes Num, I want the number of rows in the Weights table to be Num + 2 if Post = 0, and Num + 1 if Post != 0. If the number of rows in Weights needs to decrease, I'd like to keep the rows that are there and delete from the bottom. If it needs to increase I'd like to add the rows to the bottom.

I am pretty new to SQLite and have searched online for something similar but have come up empty handed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "Resize" AFTER UPDATE ON Options
BEGIN
    -- ???
END;
```

Comment: Why must this be a trigger? Can't you do this in your code?

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be a trigger, but if it could be then I'd prefer it that way.